# python2.7 multiprocess pool async vs sync

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Lots of doc write : 'apply' is for sync while 'apply_async' is for async.
And I read source code of multiprocessing (in file multiprocessing/pool.py), it says:

```
def apply(self, func, args=(), kwds={}):
    assert self._state == RUN
    return self.apply_async(func, args, kwds).get()

...
def apply_async(self, func, args=(), kwds={}, callback=None):
    assert self._state = RUN
    ....
    return result
```

It seems that apply just call apply_async, the only difference is their return values.

So my question is:

What's the real difference between sync and async ? and Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *huge* difference is the `.get()` at the end of:

```
    return self.apply_async(func, args, kwds).get()
```

`apply_async()` on its own does not block the caller:  the call to `apply_async()` returns at once, and gives you back an `AsyncResult` object.  Such objects have (among others) a `.get()` method, which *blocks* until the invoked process finishes running `func(*args, **kwds)` and returns its result.

Since `apply()` blocks until the result is ready, it's impossible to get more than one client process working simultaneously if `apply()` is all you use.  Sometimes that's what you want, but not usually.  Using `apply_async()` instead you can fire off as many tasks as you like in parallel, and retrieve their results later.

Comment: Thanks! Another question is : if I call Pool.join(), it still blocks the process, not matter use _async or not? Is there anyway I can use to get the output result without blocking ?

Comment: Yes, the *point* of `Pool.join()` is to block until all pool processes are done.  One way to get the result without blocking is to pass a callback function to `apply_async()`.  But for a long answer to that, you should open another question - comments are only good for comments ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the `get()` function. Execution is blocked until the `apply` call is done. `apply_async` will return immediately an `ApplyResult` object on which you must call `get()` to have your return value. Furthermore, the async version of the call supports a callback which will be executed when the execution is done, allowing event-driven operations.

If you supply multiple functions to `apply_async`, their return order is not guaranteed to be the same as submission order. You should check the `map()` function to get results in order.